# WCF webconfig encryption issue

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-encryption

I have encrypted my WCF Webconfig, then I have replaced my encrypted webconfig with the actual webconfig file.

Now the problem is project is not working on my pc only, it works fine on other systems.

Encryption is done as follows:

```
string provider = "RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider"; // or "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider"
string section = "connectionStrings";
protected void EncriptionWebConfig()
{
    System.Configuration.Configuration confg;
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        confg = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    else
        confg = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    ConfigurationSection confStrSect = confg.GetSection(section);
    if (confStrSect != null)
    {
        confStrSect.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider);
        confg.Save();
    }
}
```

Error is:

> Failed to decrypt using provider 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'.
>   Error message from the provider: The RSA key container could not be
>   opened

Answer (score 0):

The RSA Container and Key are machine specific.  Unless you export the container and key from the working machine to the non-working machine it will fail to open the key container.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxw286t2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: but i am on the same machine,its working on other machine but not on my machine

Comment: Is the same application encrypting and decrypting?